# Исключение при попытке подключения к удалённой БД

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть десктопное приложение, которое подключается к удалённой БД PostgreSQL. Обычно всё работает, но если отсутствует интернет-соединение, выплевывает ошибку `SEVERE: Connection error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host`, что логично. Как поймать это исключение? Оно генерируется внутри Configuration.buildSessionFactory(), но не пробрасывается наверх, только пишет в лог.

Что странно, после первой попытки программа не выполняется дальше, а пытается снова и снова подключится к БД, зацикливаясь. Можно ли через свойства конфига запретить повторные подключения?

Есть ли какой-то другой способ проверить соединение с БД?

```
try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", path);
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
    props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
    // Minimum number of JDBC connections in the pool. Hibernate default: 1
    props.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
    // Maximum number of JDBC connections in the pool. Hibernate default: 100
    props.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");
    // When an idle connection is removed from the pool (in second). Hibernate default: 0, never expire
    props.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
    // Number of prepared statements will be cached. Increase performance. Hibernate default: 0 , caching is disable
    props.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");

    props.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
    props.setProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

    Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
        .addClass(example.database.First.class)
        .addClass(example.database.Second.class)
        .setProperties(props);

    sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    LOGGER.error(ex);
    Notifications.create().text("Ошибка подключения к базе данных").showInformation();
}
```

Comment: Не [оно](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireRetryAttempts)?

Comment: @XelaNimed помогло выйти из цикла, спасибо!